# Как получить язык который установлен в android python?

Tags: android, kivy

Я разрабатываю приложение на Kivy и теперь оно нуждается в локализации. Для это нужно получить язык установленный на телефоне. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: не нужно ничего получать, размещаете файлы локализации и все

Comment: @Style-7 Но при изменении языка системы приложение тоже должно менять язык!

Comment: Андроид об этом позаботится сам

Comment: Я проверил ничего он не меняет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось довольно просто - нужно было использовать pyjnius. Код:

```
    from jnius import autoclass
    Locale = autoclass('java.util.Locale')
    lang = Locale.getDefault()
    lang = lang.getLanguage()
```